# Display Database table in a new form after clicking submit button from a previous form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'd like my button, ***See Records***, when clicked, will open a new form and display my database table through a DataGridView. However, what happens is that when I click ***See Records*** button, the new form will appear but the DataGridView won't display my database table.

Here's the code of my form4:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con;

            con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Kim\Documents\SMEMCO.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM LoanRecord", con);
            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dtbl);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dtbl;
        }
```

The ***See Records*** button was from form2. Here's my code for ***See Records***:

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form4 f4 = new Form4();
            f4.Show(); 
        }
```

[This is the DataGridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRxUt.png)

[This is my form2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TMcj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you shift the data loading into the constructor of Form4. Like this:

```
public partial class Form4 : Form
{
        public Form4()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitDataGrid();
        }

        private void InitDataGrid()
        {
            var con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Kim\Documents\SMEMCO.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM LoanRecord", con);
            var dtbl = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dtbl);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dtbl;
        }
}
```

The event of your DataGridView1 won't be raised because you don't have any cells. So the data loading can't be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to make your life so much easier than it has been so far.. chiefly swapping out how you get your data out of the db and onto a form.

Personally for this I would:

- Start a whole new project (these instructions will take less time to follow than it will me to write them, the new project means you don't wreck anything existing and you learn how it's done so you can apply the knowledge to your current app)
- Add a new DataSet type item to the project
- open it and right click anywhere, choose Add TableAdapter
- fill out the connection string, choose "query that returns rows"
- write `SELECT * FROM LoanRecord`
- call it FillAll
- finish
- go to form 1's designer
- open the data sources window (view menu, other windows)
- expand all the nodes of the DataSet
- drag the LoanRecords node onto the form
- run the app; should see all the table contents in the grid
- quit the app, make a new form
- open the designer for the new form
- in the data sources window drop the LoanRecords combo down and change the setting to Details
- drag the node to the form, note a bunch of textboxes etc have appeared
- click the bindingsource on form2 and set its modifier to public
- switch to code view of form 1, and add a class level variable for a form 2 eg `private Form2 x;`
- switch to the code view of form 2
- modify the constructor so that it accepts a DataSet parameter called `ds`
- after the initcomponent call in form2's constructor, set the `loanRecordBindingsource.DataSource = ds` equals the name of the DataSet
- after the initcomponent in form1's constructor create a new form2 passing the DataSet that form1 uses: `x = new Form2(this.yourdatasetnamehere);` and also add a call in somewhere to show this form2
- form1 and 2 now share the same data model
- double click the bindingsource **on form1** and in its CurrentChanged event handler write: `x.loanRecordBindingSource.Filter = $"[ID] = '{(this.loanRecordBindingSource.Current as DataRowView)["ID"]}'";

Now whenever you choose a record in the grid of form 1, form 2's controls will automatically refine to show the selected record on form 1 and typing anything into the controls on form2 will cause the change to be reflected on form 1

You can take the same approach with your current code if you want to; the datatable you fill and set as the DataSource for your grid, you can pass that to your second form and your second form can create a dataview that sits on top of it and you can bind all your controls to the view, then when you change the current record in the main form you can set the rowfilter of the dataview in form2.. but agh, just having to manually write out all the binding code is sooo tedious the thought of it makes me want to stick pins in my eyes! :)

Life is much easier if you use a typed DataSet, a pair of bindingsources (can even use one if you want to pass it between the forms so they share, but it's a lot more tedious wiring the controls up to a passed in bs than using the filter) looking at the same data model and then you can move them independently, or filter one so it only sees a subset of the other